# Cannot convert double - new operator

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I am having problems with a piece of code. I have this line in a C program:

```
mel[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*mellength[i]);
```

Where:

```
double *mel[16];
int mellength[16];
```

And I need to do this in C++ however I am using the "new" operator:

```
mel[i] = new double(sizeof(double)*mellength[i]);
```

Where:

```
int *mellength = new int[16];
double *mel = new double[16];
```

And I get the following error:

> error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in assignment

The full function:

```
void setup_Mel(int fft_size, int sample_rate, int *melstart, int *mellength, double *mel)
{

double fmax;
double dphi;
double fsample;
double freq;
double temp[fft_size/2];

fmax=2595*log10(8000.0f/700+1);
dphi = fmax/17;
freq = (double)sample_rate/fft_size;

for(int i=0; (i < 13); i++)
{
    melstart[i] = fft_size/2;
    mellength[i] = 0;

    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(double)*fft_size/2);
    for(int j=0; (j < fft_size/2); j++)
    {
        fsample = 2595*log10(freq*j/700 + 1);

        if((dphi * i <= fsample) && (fsample < dphi*(i+1)))
        {
            temp[j] = (fsample-dphi*i)/(dphi*(i+1)-dphi*i);
        }

        if ((dphi*(i+1) <= fsample) && (fsample < dphi*(i+2))) 
        {
            temp[j] = (fsample-dphi*(i+2))/(dphi*(i+1)-dphi*(i+2));
        }

        if ((temp[j] != 0) && (melstart[i] > j))
        {
            melstart[i] = j;
        }

        if (temp[j] != 0) mellength[i]++;
    }

   mel[i] = new double(sizeof(double)*mellength[i]);

}
}
```

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mel[i] = new double(sizeof(double)*mellength[i]);
```

Doesn't do what you think - it allocates **a single double** with the value `sizeof(double)*mellength[i]`.

To allocate an array, you'd need

```
mel[i] = new double[mellength[i]];
```

[Sample](http://ideone.com/xDY6y4)

The two versions are not equivalent:

```
double *mel = new double[16];
```

in C++ declares an array of `double`, whereas

```
double *mel[16];
```

declares an array of pointers to `double`. When you attempt to dereference the C++ variable, you get back a `double`, so of course you can't assign it to the return of a `new`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :)! I changed the code to what you suggested, I get the error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in assignment still.. Could it have anything to do with the way I am setting the variable in main? e.g. "double *mel = new double[16];" and then passing it to the function

Comment: @Phorce do you want an array of doubles (the declaration from C++) or an array of pointers to double (the declaration from C)?

Comment: I send an array of pointers to the functions, then I resize these.. So pointer[0], pointer[1]...., get's resized then I have to copy values into these doubles. I'm converting C code, I don't know why they have changed the size of the mel[i] inside the function. I'm confused now

Comment: @Phorce that doesn't answer my question. If you're having trouble answering it, you probably don't understand the requirements well enough.

Comment: I explain things bad. I believe it is an array of pointers to double declaration from C. Although, I am not sure. I am guessing it is a 2D array, and then it get's resized within the function? Really sorry about this

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is

```
mel[i] = new double[mellength[i]];
```

Your original use of `new` would attempt to allocate a single `double` and give it the value in the parentheses.